# jquery html() write function to include semantic HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first post and I'm a student with basically very little knowledge, so please be patient with me.

I am trying to use the jquery html() writing capabilities to insert semantic elements into my html page.

basically I placed empty html elements:

```
<header></header>
<footer></footer>
```

Then I wrote a jquery function:

```
    $("header").html( 
    <img src="resources/banner.png" />
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WoT Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
);
```

Not only does my jquery code not working, it also (for reasons unknown to me) stoped all my other codes from working, and they worked fine before that!
If I delete the last function (in the following JS page), everything suddenly works again.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the full JS page content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//this block of code allows for an expendable menu in the left aside site map menu, taken from: http://jsfiddle.net/VNkM2/4/ and adjusted for my purposes.
$('.header ul').hide();

$('.expandable').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('ul.expandable2').slideToggle();
    $('.ul.expandable2').not($(this).next('ul.ul.expandable2')).slideUp();
});

//this block of code displays the classes and weaves according to the order of clicking the checkboxes
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var algoType = $(this).attr("name");
    var algoDiv = "div#" + algoType;
    var displayStatus = $(algoDiv).css('display');
    if(displayStatus == "none")
    {
        $(algoDiv).show(1000)
        $(algoDiv).insertLast("span#anchor");
    }
    else{
        $(algoDiv).hide(1000)
    }

});

//this block of code inserts the header, footer and left aside menu content into each page. This allows me to edit them once and automatically update all pages.
$("header").html( 
    <img src="resources/banner.png" />
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WoT Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
);
});
```

Comment: You need to put the HTML in quotes.  `$("header").html('....')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short.. apostrophes:

```
$("header").html('<img src="resources/banner.png" /><nav><ul>...</ul></nav>');
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to use apostrophes in the text as well? Once I do, it recognizes them as though I closed the html(' ')...

Comment: for example: $("header").html('My name is Mc\'Toad'). In other words you escape it using \'